# Escape inbuild Coldfusion Function

Tags: mysql, hash

I encountered a old code, where one developer has created a table column named HASH, and this is an in build CF Function,

it is being used at enormous places, so i have a situation where i need to send the information stored in the column HASH to the email.

how can i escape this function to be treated as simple variable and let do the work what i want it to do.

I am trying something like this

```
<cfset a = "#hash#">
```

Any Idea?

Comment: You could have scoped the variable too `queryname.hash`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it, i called it with backticks from the query as:

```
`hash` as strpasswd
```

and called the strpasswd and it worked,

cheers